# Подстановка id элемента при выборе элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Есть следующий код:

```
var f = document.getElementById("colors");
f.onchange = function() {
    var n = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'),
        l = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    for (var j = 0; j < n.length; j++)
        if (l.length >= 1) {
            n[j].disabled = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++)
                l[i].disabled = false;
        } else {
            n[j].disabled = false;
        }
}
```

В коде на HTML странице есть ряд `id`. Например: `id="home"`, `id="morning"`.
Необходимо чтобы при клике на `id="morning"` вместо

```
var f = document.getElementById("colors");
```

в данный скрипт поступала следующая строка:

```
var f = document.getElementById("morning");
```

Всего на странице 8 уникальных `id`.

Нужно чтобы при клике на каждый из них в скрипт поступала своя определенная строка.

Моя последняя редакция кода:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="id1()">Текст</a>
```

JS:

```
var ids = 0;
function id1() {
   var ids = 'colors';
   alert(ids);
};
var f = document.getElementById(ids);
f.onchange = function() {
    var n = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'),
        l = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    for (var j = 0; j < n.length; j++)
        if (l.length >= 1) {
            n[j].disabled = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++)
                l[i].disabled = false;
        } else {
            n[j].disabled = false;
        }
}
```

Получается запись `var f = document.getElementById(0);`, а должно быть `var f = document.getElementById(ids);`.
Таким образом я хочу избежать дублирования кода, чтобы для всех 8 параметров просто менять значения `ids` с `0` на `'color'`, `'home'` и так далее.

Comment: @ Alex Пойдет любой вариант, который сможет сделать чтобы работало.
С this.id я уже пробовал. Проблема оказалась в другом.
Есть ссылки: <a href="#aa" id="1" onclick="id1()">link1</a>
Таких ссылок всего 8. 
<a href="#ab" id="2" onclick="id2()">link2</a>
<a href="#ac" id="3" onclick="id3()">link3</a>
Жмякаем на id1() и срабатывает функция:
function id1(val) {var ids = 'colors';};
Но к этому моменту функция в этой функции мы получили ids='colors';
Но, как показано на примере выше, остальная часть скрипта не сработает, т.к. она уже выполнена при загрузке страницы. Дублировать код не хочется 8 раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код `var f = ...` и `f.onchange = ...` исполняется в момент загрузки скрипта или, если он расположен внутри какой-либо функции (например, функции, исполняемой после того, как документ загружен), после вызова данной функции. Можно попытаться извратиться, поменяв текст скрипта (а именно `id` выбираемого элемента) и исполнив его заново, но это не звучит как хорошее решение.

Если необходимо добавить обработчик события `change` нескольким известным заранее элементам, можно просто по очереди добавлять обработчик каждому из них:

```
function addChangeEventListener(id)
{
    var f = document.getElementById(id);
    f.onchange = function() {
        var n = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
        var l = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        for (var j = 0; j < n.length; j++)
        {
            if (l.length >= 1)
            {
                n[j].disabled = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++)
                {
                    l[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                n[j].disabled = false;
            }
        }
    };
}

var ids = ["home", "morning", "colors"];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
{
    addChangeEventListener(ids[i]);
}
```

Код внутри обработчика я не трогал (не считая фигурных скобок).

Comment: Нет, вы видимо не так поняли. Смысл в том, что могут быть на странице может быть нажат любой из 8 ID. В результате только от него должны передаться данные в f.
На данный момент я повесил это все на onclick="id1()"
В функции id1() присваиваю переменным var ids = 'colors';
Остается только вопрос, как теперь обратиться к описанной выше функции чтобы в получилась вот такая запись. var f = document.getElementById(ids); 
В шапку поставил измененный код.

Comment: @anj1817 а в чем проблема с тем, чтобы повесить обработчик события на все 8 элементов при загрузке страницы, как сделано в моём коде? В рамках функции `addChangeEventListener` `f` указывает на конкретный элемент. Вы пробовали использовать данный код у себя? А если вы хотите, чтобы в ответе был представлен полный пример, нужно в вопрос добавить соответствующий HTML-код. `<a href="#" onclick="id1()">Текст</a>` вообще не помогает понять, что это за 8 элементов такие, на которые вешаются обработчики события `change`, да ещё и внутри которых находятся `checkbox`'ы.

Comment: @anj1817 и заодно [упрощённый пример кода](http://jsfiddle.net/y6225Lny/) для демонстрации его работоспособности.

Comment: если честно, то я не въехал, как это должно работать. Я по сути просто пытаюсь избежать дублирования кода. Как я уже писал в комменте под вопросом, есть 8 ссылок, на каждую из них повешена разная onclick функция. Но в результате срабатывания каждой из них должны получаться разные значения переменной f, которые потом обрабатываются в f.onchange = function() {} Вопрос теперь лишь в том, как подвязать f.onchange = function() {} к function id1() {} и прочим таким функциям так, чтобы она срабатывала по клику, а не при загрузке страницы.

Comment: @anj1817 а вы в моём коде видите дублирование? Почему обработчик события `change` для элемента должен добавляться только по клику на какой-то элемент? Почему вас не устраивает добавление обработчиков при загрузке страницы? И добавьте-таки минимальный полный пример HTML в вопрос. Это может прояснить вашу проблему. На данный момент в вопросе нет элементов с ID `"home"`, `"morning"`, `"colors"`, не говоря уж про checkbox'ы в них.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что сразу Вас не понял. Я пока слабо разбираюсь в javascript. Ваша идея оказалась полностью правильной. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

используя jQuery можно написать все намного короче
повесив на каждый элемент например класс "color" получение элемента будет выглядеть так

```
$('.color').on('change', function(){
    var f = $(this);
    // Далее ваш код
    var n = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
    var l = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    for (var j = 0; j < n.length; j++){
        if (l.length >= 1){
            n[j].disabled = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
                l[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }else{
            n[j].disabled = false;
        }
    }
});
```